# How can I test is start time is less than end time

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb .net.

I have two dropdownList named startTimeDDL and endTimeDDL. Than I am using loop to enter in time inside those dropdownlist. So look below and that will be inside those dropdownList. notie the format is hh:mm am/pm.

```
12:00 AM
12:30 AM
01:00 AM
01:30 AM
02:00 AM
...
11:30 PM
```

Problem:

I want to check to see if `startTimeS(String)` is less than `endTimeS(String).
startTimeS >= endTimeS`

for some reason my  code is not checking for AM or PM. it only check for numbers. so for example below line will work fine bc 12:00 is less than 12:30. which is fine and it wont go inside the if statment.

```
12:00 AM >= 12:30 AM - works: doesnt goes inside if statment
```

But below line will this 12:00 is greater than 1:00 and it will go inside the if statment. this is wrong, as you can see if igone the am or pm. it should not go inside the the if statment bc 12:00 AM is less than 1:00AM.

```
12:00 AM >= 01:00 AM - error: goes inside the if statment
```

How can I modify my code to test for time?

Code:

```
'Start time is less than end time
If "#" & StartTimeS & "#" >= "#" & EndTimeS & "#" Then
    ErrorS &= " - Start Time has to be less than End Time.<br/>"
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are comparing strings, not dates. Convert your times to the proper `DateTime` object and compare those.

```
Dim c, d as DateTime
c = Convert.ToDateTime(startTimeS)
d = Convert.ToDateTime(endTimeS)
return c >= d
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to DateTime before comparing them. As of now, you are just comparing strings

```
If DateTime.Parse(StartTimeS) >= DateTime.Parse(EndTimeS) Then
            'do you stuff
        end if
```

[Here is a working example : fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GnCqec)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the comboboxes are populated with the same data in the same order, you can use their index locations to check for greater than or less than.  You would expect the selectedIndex for the startTime to be less than or equal to the endTime.

```
If startTimeDDL.SelectedIndex <= endTimeDDL.SelectedIndex Then
    ' Do something
End If
```